# Tensor product of two cyclic modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Given a commutative ring $A$ (with identity) and two cyclic $A$-modules, $M$ and $N$ with generators $x$ and $y$, respectively.

How do you show that $\mathrm{Ann}(x\otimes_A y) = \mathrm{Ann}(x) + \mathrm{Ann}(y)$?

---

It is simple to show that $\mathrm{Ann}(x\otimes y) \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(x) + \mathrm{Ann}(y)$ by taking the acting element inside the tensor.

**My attempt**:

For any pure tensor $(r_1x)\otimes (r_2 y) = (r_1r_2)(x\otimes y)$, so that any general tensor can be written as $r (x\otimes y)$ and thus $M \otimes N$ is cyclic with generator $x\otimes y$. Therefore $M \otimes N \cong A / \mathrm{Ann}(x\otimes y)$

Let $I = \mathrm{Ann}(x) + \mathrm{Ann}(y)$. (They're both ideals)

I defined a homomorphism $\psi: A/I \rightarrow M\otimes N$; $r + I \mapsto r (x \otimes y)$. It is well-defined and surjective. If it were injective, then we'd have $A/I \cong M\otimes N \cong A/\mathrm{Ann}(x\otimes y)$ and because of the first inclusion the two ideals would be equal (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is equivalent to the isomorphism $A/I \otimes_A A/J \cong A/(I+J)$ of $A$-modules. Actually they are also isomorphic as $A$-algebras. Beyond the usual proof which you can read everywhere, there is a one-line proof with the Yoneda-Lemma.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone interested, there's a proof of that isomorphism [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/the-tensor-product-of-the-quotients-of-a-commutative-ring-by-two-ideals-is-isomorphic-to-the-quotient-by-their-sum/)

Comment: $A/I$ is the initial $A$-algebra whose structural morphism kills $I$. It follows that $A/I \otimes A/J$ is the initial $A$-algebra whose structural morphism kills $I$ and $J$, i.e. $I+J$. Hence this is $A/(I+J)$.